# Can’t read Json Data form AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs

**Hi,**

I’m new to AngularJS and I’ve been struggling to read some Json data form AngularJS service but to no avail!, can someone help me?

**The AngularJS service:**

```
  (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myService').service('myDataService', myDataService);

  myDataService.$inject = ['$q'];

  function myDataService($q) {
    return {
      getMyData: getMyData
    };

    function getMyData() {
      return $q.when({
        "data": [{
          "company": "ABC",
          "date": "25/09/2015",
          "hrData": [{
            "name": "Mark",
            "dept": "891 2 1",
            "empId": 77
          }, {
            "name": "James",
            "dept": "400 1 1",
            "empId": 340
          }, {
            "name": "Sam",
            "dept": "393 1 1",
            "empId": 220
          }, {
            "name": "Kumar",
            "dept": "M20 1 0",
            "empId": -287
          }, {
            "name": "Ric",
            "dept": "L21 2 1",
            "empId": 347
          }]
        }, {
          "company": "XYZ",
          "date": "25/09/2015",
          "hrData": [{
            "name": "Vijay",
            "dept": "664 2 1",
            "empId": 164
          }, {
            "name": "Judy",
            "dept": "UNKNOWN",
            "empId": null
          }, {
            "name": "Jak",
            "dept": "834 1 1",
            "empId": 423
          }]
        }]
      })
    }
  }
    })();
```

**The code I'm using to read data form the service:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myPlanner">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>statusAlertsWebclient</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower styles dependencies -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- css files will be automatically insert here -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body data-ng-controller="MainController as vm">
    <!--[if lt IE 10]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <div ui-view>

    </div>

{{theData | json}}



    <!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower script dependencies -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <!-- js files will be automatically insert here -->
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- inject:partials -->
    <!-- angular templates will be automatically converted in js and inserted here -->
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- build:tfnsw-info -->
    <!-- This section will be replased by the version number in package.json -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

  </body>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myPlanner', ['myService']);
    app.controller('MainController', function($scope, myDataService) {
    $scope.theData = myDataService.getMyData.data;
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I wrong in saying that the getMyData() function is not executed at any point? + the promise issue pointed out by Robba already

Comment: possibly, as I'm getting 'TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'then'' after trying Robba's suggested solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getMyData` function returns a promise. You should use `then()` on it to wait for the result:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myPlanner', ['myService']);
    app.controller('MainController', function($scope, myDataService) {
        myDataService.getMyData().then(function(data) {
            $scope.theData = data;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: check your syntax

Comment: Thanks Robba, after trying your solution now I have this error -->TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'then'